# Reviewing "Low Quality" Answers when they refer to questions that are themselves Low Quality

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

While reviewing the "Low Quality" from my "Review Queues", I often come up to answers to questions that are themselves low quality (and most times that is obvious from their score / has been raised ). What should my reaction be? I am currently skipping most of those, as their quality seems to me irrelevant. Any other reaction would probably require more time from my part.

I could dedicate some time to look at them closely, but, honestly, I feel a bit de-motivated, since I feel like I spend time without a real impact.

What would be a proper reaction when dealing with reviewing a  "Low Quality" answer to a Question that I feel is, or is marked, or is soon to be marked "Low Quality"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't assume reviewing answers to low-quality questions is a waste of time. There's no guarantee that a question you think is low-quality is going to be closed and/or deleted; and even if it is, it can be sitting around for a long time before that happens (especially on smaller sites).

If you can't immediately judge the quality of the answer and you don't want to spend the time reviewing it then hit "Skip"; *Don't* hit anything else on the assumption that the question won't be around long enough for it to matter.

If you do review the answer... Judge *the answer* on its content, exactly as you would in any other case. It's perfectly possible to give a good, well researched and complete answer to a low effort question that *asks* for a low-quality answer. Just because the question asks for it, doesn't give the answerer a free-pass on posting low-quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/4751173).

Second, if applicable, you can flag to close such questions (if appropriate) as Unclear what you're asking, Too broad or Off-Topic. For example, on Stack Overflow, answers which consist of barely more than a link are generally frowned upon and can be safely deleted, but if the question literally asks

> Please suggest me a library so that I can *foo* the *bar*

and the answer says

> You can use the [*FooBar* library](https://example.com) for this purpose.

I'd generally choose <kbd>Looks OK</kbd> when reviewing the answer.

Comment: A link-only answer to an off-topic question? I'd prefer to "Recommend Deletion". (I assume you've already checked that the link isn't spam.)

Comment: "Looks OK" logic suggested here feels somewhat flawed. I mean yeah that link answers the (off-topic) question asked but how that makes it OK. Or, what makes OK better fit for this review item than Skip

Comment: Well, 'Looks OK' essentially means 'it should not be deleted', and I can't edit it in a better shape. I'm generally not going to do the author's work, and I don't see why it should be deleted, according to the guidelines laid out in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232).